# How to work with conditional template steps with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner in AngularJS and I have a situation where the registration process can take 3 routes and each of the route has multiple steps. User can choose any of the routes

Can someone suggest me how can I achieve this. I'm worried, as I have a deadline to implement this.

I have not yet started any coding as of now. As I'm new, I'm trying to start with right direction instead of writing the code and struggle with that. Please advise me the best approach

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide the code you have tried and elaborate more on this.

Comment: Hi @Shashank, I have not yet started any coding as of now. As I'm new, I'm trying to start with right direction instead of writing the code and struggle with that. Please advise me the best approach.

Comment: @Tarak, do you use `ng-route` or `ui-route` for routing?

Comment: In angular choosing, the router has something to do with the way you design the project .so select one you are flexible with, I will recommend `ui-router`

Comment: @AbhilashPA, I will be using ui-router only

Comment: @Tarak, So whats the problem? You can create states for each steps of all the routes (3 routes). And add proper buttons to next state in each states.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngRoute or uiRouter (stateprovider or routeprovider) for navigating through steps of a single route or among multiple routes.
Reference Links:
[ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example),
[ui Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

You can also navigate using $state.go in controller.